# ExcelPackage not Saving programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to edit an existing excel file with .xlsx extension using C#,but it is not saving the new value.My code is as follows.Can anybody help me?

```
 string path = @"D:\Demo\test.xlsx"    ;  
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.GetFileName(path));
          using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
           {
                 ExcelWorkbook workBook = xlPackage.Workbook;
                 ExcelWorksheet ws = workBook.Worksheets[1];
                 ws.Cells[8, 6].Value = 25;
                 xlPackage.Save();
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `@` symbol before your path string to prevent automatic stripping or manually escape your `\` characters

```
string path = @"D:\test\test.xslx";
```

Or

```
string path = "D:\\test\\test.xslx";
```